# How to define constant in codeigniter library constructor from config?

Tags: codeigniter

My library class contains a constant with a string value.
I want to set its value from the config item defined in the codeigniter config file.

Comment: you can do this thing in `config/constants` file

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this in `config/config.php` AND `config/constants.php`.
>   you just need to write below kind of thing

```
i.e
define('PAY_AMOUNT', '$120');
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is defined at the config file and its value different in testing and production environment. Its a third party account key and its value change between the environment.

Eg:

```
$config['my_key'] = 'skdflksd1654612'; // for testing
$config['my_key'] = 'poikjij788miomk'; // for production
```

I have a library in which a constant value need to set from this config item. That's my requirement.

```
Class Mylibrary{
   const MYKEY = 'skdflksd1654612'; // for testing
   const MYKEY = 'poikjij788miomk'; // for production
   function __construct()
  {

  }
}
```